# What is the kinematic model of a quadrotor/quadcoptor with an X configuration?

Tags: mobile-robot, quadcopter, kinematics, velocity, screw-theory

I would like to know what is the kinematic model of a quadcopter in X-configuration. Basically I want the relation mapping rotor speed to the body twist (or body frame velocity).

```
       rotor speed = H . body_twist  ==> What is this equation?
```

The rotor speed matrix is             ==> (4 x 1) matrix
The body frame velocity/body twist is ==> (6 x 1) matrix
The H is                              ==> (4 x 6) matrix

I would like to know what is this H matrix for a quadrotor in X-config.

For reference, the kinematic model of a Mechanum Wheel robot is as follows :

[image: KINEMATIC MODEL OF 4 WHEEL MECHANUM BASE]

I would like to know what is the similar model for a quadcopter in X-config.

Reference : Modern Robotics, Lynch and Park, Cambridge U